# How to achieve this special kind of transpose in excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have this data sheet here in this specific table structure ...

[image]

The goal is to extract Vorname, Nachname, Barcode into a separate sheet but in this transposed structure ...

[image]

I tried transpose and then manipulating the arguments to achieve the goal, but nothing worked, and I couldn't find a tutorial online that goes along with my case here.

Tables in text:

```
Start:

Vorname       Nachname         Barcode
Ahmed         Mahmoud          barcode1
Zakaria       Atef             barcode2

Goal:

Vorname       Ahmed
Nachname      Mahmoud
Barcode       barcode1
Vorname       Zakaria
Nachname      Atef
Barcode       barcode2
```

Comment: In Excel you may record a VBA macro which can show you the required code

Comment: You could also do this in Power query. But your screenshot of data is virtually useless for providing proper help. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld What is so unclear about the screenshots ? It is super easy to understand. the rows in the first screenshot need to be transposed, but in the customized way showing in the second screenshot

Comment: I guess what I wrote was not clear. ***It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet.***  I cannot help you without reproducing the problem. I cannot do that without data on my worksheet.  I am not going to spend the time re-typing it from your screenshot, especially when you can make that task simple by posting as text.  We are all volunteers here.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld apologies for the inconvenience. Post is edited.

Comment: Now that I can see clearly what you are trying to do, it is a simple **UNPIVOT** operation. There are multiple examples on this forum, using Power Query (simple), VBA (somewhat more complex), or formulas (most complicated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple UNPIVOT operation. Easily handled with Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ or Office 365

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- Select ALL the columns, then `Transform => Unpivot`

and your done.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table12"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Vorname", type text}, {"Nachname", type text}, {"Barcode", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Columns"
```

**Source**
[image]

**Results**
[image]